# Failed to compile Vue project and getting "Mixed spaces and tabs no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs" error

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Please find the below details with error.

Error Details:
Failed to compile.

./src/components/Header.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

H:\project\VueProjects\stock-trader\src\components\Header.vue
27:2  error  Mixed spaces and tabs  no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Header.vue

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <router-link to="/" class="navbar-brand">Stock Trader</router-link>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <router-link to="/portfolio" activeClass="active" tag="li"
            ><a>Portfolio</a></router-link
          >
          <router-link to="/stocks" activeClass="active" tag="li"
            ><a>Stocks</a></router-link
          >
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">End day</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a
              href="#"
              class="dropdown-toggle"
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              role="button"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false"
              >Save & Load <span class="caret"></span
            ></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Load Data</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Stock Trader</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x"
      crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53E05.jpg)

Please advise.

Edited part after resolution of first query.

Desired result screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY921.jpg)

Result getting screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRQVb.jpg)

Comment: Piyush, which editor are you using? Have you tried converting all white space (select all) to tabs or spaces? In VS Code there's a Select Indentation option in the bottom right corner that will allow you to indent/convert all white space, thats how I do it.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Yes, I'm using VS Code  but now my bootstrap is not working. I've edited my post and attached the desired result screenshot vs result getting screenshot. Please check

Comment: Hmm have you checked the console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: It's solved, I downgraded the bootstrap version and installed it and it worked. :)

Comment: Oh nice! Good job, Ill post my original answer here so you can mark it correct? No big deal either way, but glad you got everything figured out.

Comment: Sure Dave, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editors like VS code have an option to convert all whitespace to tabs or spaces which will prevent your node package manager build from complaining about mixed whitespace encodings (tabs vs spaces). Try clicking 'Select Indentation' located in the bottom right corner in VS code, or look for (or Google) an option for whatever editor you are using, to convert all the whitespace to spaces or tabs.